# Cast Argument for abstract method with Type parameter

Tags: java

I don't know if its completely possible to do this, but here it goes.

I have an abstract class. Lets call it class 'A'. It looks like this:

```
public abstract class A <E, T>
```

It also has the following abstract method.

```
public abstract Object getEntityId(E entity);
```

So I can create more classes extending the A class as long as I implement the abstract getEntityId method. For example a class called 'ExtendedA'.

But also I have a secondary class, called it B. It's not abstract and goes like this :

```
public class B<T>
```

(notice the type parameter)

B has a field of type A, which should be an extended class of A (such a ExtendedA). It also contains a List of T such as this:

```
private A<?,?> myA;
private List<T> myList;
```

At some point, I need to invoke the abstract getEntityId method in class B for every element in myList, but I can't quite get the cast correctly. I feel like I'm missing something really basic.

```
for (T t : myList) {
    if (myA.getEntityId(t)!=null) {//does not compile and I can't grasp how should I cast it.
                        
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show all this code as a single class? It's hard to follow with all the words in the middle.

Comment: How should this work? `E` of `A` is not the same as `T` of `B`.

Comment: If I get this right your `E` from `A` would be the same as your `T` in `B` ?

Comment: myA should be defined as `private A<T,?> myA` or `private A<? extends T,?> myA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `B` class looks like this:

```
public class B<T> {
  private A<?,?> myA;

  void someMethod() {
    for (T t : myList) {
      if (myA.getEntityId(t)!=null) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then sure, it won't compile: the parameter of `getEntityId` is `?`, and you're trying to pass it a `T`. `?` doesn't mean "any type", it means "a specific type, just one that I don't know".

To pass a `T` to `getEntityId()`, the first type parameter of `A` needs to be `T`:

```
  private A<T,?> myA;
```

Comment: Yeah, if I carefully declare correctly the type E in the extended A classes and T in the B classes, this works just fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the code to work, Make it a complete getter method than trying to set value in runtime as it is completely illegal to do it on a wildcard. Either pass the reference private A myA or private A<(some known reference),?> myA or remove the parameter from myA.getEntityId(t)

Also declare a anonymous class and implement the method before calling the method getEntityId()

```
public class B<T>{

private A<T,?> myA;
private List<T> myList;

public void anycall(){

    for (T t : myList) {
    if (myA.getEntityId(t)!=null) {

    }
}

}
}
```